# How do I add a migration for uniqueness on two columns where I lowercase one column?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing, database-migration

I have two columns that store strings, `:column_a`, and `:column_b`.

I know that I can do:

`add_index :table, [:column_a, :column_b], unique: true`

But, I need to achieve the following:

`add_index :table, [:column_a, 'lower(column_b)'], unique: true`

This of course errors out when I try to migrate.

I get an error that `lower(column_b)` is not a column.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Honestly, at this point, I'm thinking of just having a column called `column_b_lowercase` that I index on.

Comment: Well I once did something similiar in C#, but instead of lowercase was becasue accent. I just create a `not_accent` column

Comment: If all else fails just do it in SQL directly. Rails supports arbitrary SQL statements in migrations.

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah, I decided to just do that.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just use SQL. Here is the code.

```
class AddUniqueIndexingForLowercaseColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_column_a_lowercase_column_b_index ON table(column_a, lower(column_b))"
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :table, :table_column_a_lowercase_column_b_index
  end
end
```